# Нормально ли в UWP приложении держать много открытых файловых потоков? Ошибка обновления файла "Не удается удалить заменяемый файл"

Tags: c#, uwp

Есть дерево папок, в некоторых папках есть файлы, в которые нужно писать периодически информацию, то есть обновлять их. Бывает так, что при попытке записи в файл вылетает исключение:

> System.Exception: Не удается удалить заменяемый файл. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070497)

Судя по всему это в английской версии:

> System.Exception: Unable to remove the file to be replaced. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070497)

Сохраняю в основном таким методом (строка кода из большого метода с блокировкой доступа к файлу из нескольких потоков):

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, encryptedText, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
```

И вот я подумал, а что если держать файловые потоки открытыми? Создать словарь, в который сложить все потоки. Про какие потоки я говорю видно из кода ниже (понятно, что я их не буду оборачивать в using в таком случае)

```
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
}
```

Но из-за жизненного цикла UWP приложения возникает проблема с открытием и закрытием этих самых потоков. UWP приложение может завершить работу в любой момент, если его просто свернуть, и на всё про всё будет дано 5 секунд. Да, есть возможность запросить время для работы в фоне, но это можно отключить в настройках Windows 10 и не во всех версиях Windows 10 это работает.

Пробовал даже в цикле делать несколько попыток записать файл, иногда это срабатывает, иногда нет. Вообще с файлами происходит какая-то магия. Я так и не понял, почему работа с файлами имеет такие проблемы. Доступ к файлам, повторюсь, я залочил и пишет всегда один поток.

Если держать открытыми файловые потоки, то после каждой записи буду вызывать

```
await stream.FlushAsync();
```

Как вообще лучше поступить?

**UPDATE**:

https://github.com/kpreisser/AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim

Блокирую доступ к файлам так:

```
    public async Task Save(PropertyInfo properties, StorageFolder dumpFolder)
    {
        // ReadLock - чтобы нельзя было удалить папку, пока внутри неё пишутся файлы
        // При удалении папки вызываем WriteLock.
        StorageFolder parentFolder = await dumpFolder.GetParentAsync();

        using (var releaser = _lockProvider.Paths.GetLock(parentFolder))
        using (await releaser.Lock.GetReadLockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        using (var releaserProps = _lockProvider.Paths.GetLock(dumpFolder, PROPERTY_FILENAME))
        using (await releaserProps.Lock.GetWriteLockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            // Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Save)}. {_lockProvider.Paths.GetLockInfo()}");

           // Много кода 
           await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, encryptedText, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        }
    }
```

Классы, которые используются:

```
public class FileReaderWriterLockProvider
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockProvider<string> _paths;

    public FileReaderWriterLockProvider()
    {
        _paths = new ReaderWriterLockProvider<string>();
    }

    public Releaser GetLock(StorageFolder folder, string objectName = "")
    {
        string key = generateKey(folder, objectName);
        var releaser = _paths.GetLock(key);
        return new Releaser(releaser);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получить список блокировок. Изначально метод создавался для отладки и логирования.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetLockInfo()
    {
        return _paths.GetLockInfo();
    }

    private static string generateKey(StorageFolder folder, string objectName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(folder.Path, objectName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Класс, удаляющий блокировку из коллекции блокировок во время вызова метода <see cref="IDisposable.Dispose"/>
    /// </summary>
    public struct Releaser : IDisposable
    {
        private ReaderWriterLockProvider<string>.LockPairReleaser _releaser;

        public AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim Lock
        {
            get
            {
                if (_releaser.IsDisposed)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(_releaser));
                }

                return _releaser.LockPair.Lock;
            }
        }

        internal Releaser(ReaderWriterLockProvider<string>.LockPairReleaser releaser)
        {
            _releaser = releaser;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _releaser.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

ReaderWriterLockProvider

```
public class ReaderWriterLockProvider<TKey>
{
    private readonly object _sync;
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, LockPair> _locks;

    public ReaderWriterLockProvider()
    {
        _sync = new object();
        _locks = new Dictionary<TKey, LockPair>();
    }

    public LockPairReleaser GetLock(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (!_locks.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _locks.Add(key, new LockPair(new AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim()));
            }

            var pair = _locks[key];
            pair.Increment();
            return new LockPairReleaser(pair, key, _locks, _sync);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получить список блокировок. Для отладки и логирования.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetLockInfo()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            return _locks.Keys.Select(key => key.ToString()).Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + Environment.NewLine + workingSentence);
        }
    }

    public struct LockPairReleaser : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly LockPair _lockPair;
        private readonly TKey _key;
        private readonly Dictionary<TKey, LockPair> _locks;
        private readonly object _sync;

        private volatile bool _isDisposed;

        public bool IsDisposed
        {
            get { return _isDisposed; }
        }

        internal LockPairReleaser(LockPair lockPair, TKey key, Dictionary<TKey, LockPair> locks, object sync)
        {
            _isDisposed = false;
            _lockPair = lockPair;
            _key = key;
            _locks = locks;
            _sync = sync;
        }

        public LockPair LockPair
        {
            get { return _lockPair; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _isDisposed = true;
                int value = _lockPair.Decrement();
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    _locks.Remove(_key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LockPair

```
public class LockPair
{
    private int _count;

    public AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim Lock { get; }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return Volatile.Read(ref _count); }
    }

    public LockPair(AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim @lock)
    {
        Lock = @lock;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    }

    public int Decrement()
    {
        return Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как именно вам помогут потоки? Вы же перезписываете файл при каждой записи в него, а не дописываете в конец.

Comment: @tym32167, понятия не имею. Я говорю же, у меня впечатление, что происходит необъяснимая магия. Например, я предположил, что если файл будет открыт на запись, то никто не сможет вклиниться и не дать мне его записать. Я нагугливал, что бывали такие проблемы из-за антивируса, не знаю правда ли это.

Comment: `строка кода из большого метода с блокировкой доступа к файлу из нескольких потоков` как эта блокировка выглядит?

Comment: @tym32167, Берётся путь к файлу и его имя, из этого получается строка. Помещается строка в словарь в качестве ключа. Из словаря по этому ключу мы достаём AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim. Там куча классов, но в итоге это выглядит как using (var releaserProps = _lockProvider.Paths.GetLock(dumpFolder, PROPS_FILENAME)) using (await releaserProps.Lock.GetWriteLockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)). Его взял отсюда: https://github.com/kpreisser/AsyncReaderWriterLockSlim

Comment: _lockProvider.Paths.GetLock(dumpFolder, PROPS_FILENAME)) возвращает struct Releaser, который в методе Dispose освобождает блокировку, и удаляет её из словаря

Comment: В вопрос добавьте все эти подробности, в комментах это читать невозможно же

Comment: ну и, какова вероятность того, что 2 файла одновременно попытаются добавиться в словарь с попыткой взять лок на запись?

Comment: @tym32167, дополнил вопрос деталями. Судя по логам, никогда не заходили два потока одновременно в метод записи. Запись в этот файл вызывается только в одном методе.

Comment: Нашёл способ узнать, какие процессы обращались к файлу и было ли успешно такое обращение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946343/Как-узнать-историю-доступа-к-файлу-Какие-процессы-его-открывали-и-т-д

Comment: я бы попробовал поставить жесткую блокировку при записи чтобы одновременно запись была только в 1 файл (то есть блокировка без вашего словаря, с одним только `ReaderWriterLockSlim` или вообще с одним семафором, чтобы и чтения не было), и если всё равно будут проблемы, то что то не так и функцией записи; если всё бует ок - то прблема у вас. Кстати, вы не показали как вы читаете данные