# Как узнать историю доступа к файлу. Какие процессы его открывали и т.д.?

Tags: c#, windows, файлы, процесс, мониторинг

Иногда в приложении вылетают исключения, что файл недоступен, так как открыт другим процессом. При том, открыт этот файл только в моей программе и прописана синхронизация доступа к файлу посредством блокировок.

Код создания блокировок представлен в вопросе: [Нормально ли в UWP приложении держать много открытых файловых потоков? Ошибка обновления файла "Не удается удалить заменяемый файл"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941412/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-uwp-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотреть, какие процессы обращались к файлу можно с помощью программы

[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Нужно лишь создать фильтр по пути к файлу нажав сочетание клавиш `Ctrl + L`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]